# Retorno de objeto obtenido con fetch en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch

Soy nuevo en JavaScript y estoy tratando de exportar un objeto con algunos datos que recojo de un archivo JSON.

El problema es que los datos del objeto son correctos justo antes de salir de la función, dentro del `fetch`, pero al salir el arreglo de objetos se vacía.

```javascript
const setEnumContent = () => {
    let enumContent = [];
    let chapterNumber = 0;
    
    fetch(SRC_REFS_DATA_CONTENTS)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                if (element.type == "chapter") {
                    let content = {};

                    content.reference = element.reference;
                    content.chapter = (++chapterNumber);
                    
                    enumContent.push(content);
                }                
            });
        });

    return enumContent;
}
```

Si imprimo el tamaño del objeto retorno me devuelve el valor `0`, es decir:

```javascript
console.log(setEnumContent().length);
```

Pero si realizo una impresión dentro de la función de la promesa sí funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tienes un problema con las peticiones asíncronas. Cuando se ejecuta `return` el contenido de `enumContent` aún no ha sido obtenido. ¿Cómo llamas a esta función? La solución está en cambiar la manera en la que llamas a la función para permitir que trates los datos cuando éstos hayan sido obtenidos, y no solo modificando tu función.

Comment: Que tendría que añadir para hacer que el retorno solo se de cuando los datos se obtengan?, la función se llama para crear un listado que permita comparar en que capitulo se encuentra.

Comment: Estoy redactando una respuesta. Es compleja, así que voy a tardar unos minutos más.

Comment: Gracias héroe sin capa :D

Comment: He terminado de redactar la respuesta con las dos soluciones que puedes usar. Espero que te sea de ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Qué tal te fue? Si no entiendes alg o tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en plantearla en los comentarios.

Comment: Tuve que replantearme la forma en que se llamaría la función y entrar a estudiar un poco el tema de la función de retrollamada pero se logró, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta pulsando en el icono **✓** que hay junto a ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando invocas una función asíncrona, ésta no se resuelve hasta que ha completado su trabajo (por ejemplo, la petición al servidor que estás solicitando).

Eso significa que el código que va tras el `fetch`, el `return enumContent`, se ejecuta **ANTES** que las funciones definidas dentro de los `then()`.

Tienes varias formas de resolver el problema. La más sencilla es [proporcionando una función de retrollamada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) como parámetro, pero la más elegante es haciendo uso de [funciones asíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Te pongo un ejemplo de cada una de ellas y una descripción superficial de cada solución.

### Función de retrollamada

Una retrollamada es un método de comunicación entre procesos por el cual proporcionamos como parámetro una función que puede ser llamada una o varias veces cuando se produzca un evento (por ejemplo, al finalizar un trabajo).

```js
const SRC_REFS_DATA_CONTENTS =
  "https://api.github.com/users/ojgarciab/events/public";

const setEnumContent = (retrollamada) => {
  let enumContent = [];
  let chapterNumber = 0;
  fetch(SRC_REFS_DATA_CONTENTS)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(element => {
      if (element.type == "PushEvent") {
        enumContent.push({
          reference: element.repo.name,
          chapter: ++chapterNumber,
        });
      }
    });
    /* Aquí hacemos la retrollamada con los datos */
    retrollamada(enumContent);
  });
}

/* Ahora llamamos a la función proporcionando qué hacer en la retrollamada */
setEnumContent(datos => console.log(datos));
```

### Función asíncrona

Una función asíncrona es una función que puede ejecutar en su interior otras funciones asíncronas como si se ejecutaran de manera secuencial (usando `await`), ejecutándose cada tarea después de que la anterior haya finalizado.

```js
const SRC_REFS_DATA_CONTENTS =
  "https://api.github.com/users/ojgarciab/events/public";

/* Definimos la función como asíncrona */
const setEnumContent = async () => {
  let enumContent = [];
  let chapterNumber = 0;
  /* Obtenemos la respuesta y los datos */
  const respuesta = await fetch(SRC_REFS_DATA_CONTENTS);
  const data = await respuesta.json();
  /* Procesamos los datos obtenidos */
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (element.type == "PushEvent") {
      enumContent.push({
        reference: element.repo.name,
        chapter: ++chapterNumber,
      });
    }
  });
  /* Devolvemos los valores */
  return enumContent;
}

/* Ahora llamamos a la función tratándola como una promesa */
setEnumContent().then(datos => console.log(datos));
```